# Yii Framework Messages - changing core messages

Tags: yii, message

I got little problem on my hand with Yii messages.
I am messing with 3party code and just wanted to change language from english to espaniol

I changed main.php variables

```
$config = array(
```

'basePath' => dirname(**FILE**) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'mySite',

```
'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
'language' => 'es',
```

and it should be Spanish now. But it isn't. 
Also the script I am messing with have its own translation system inside.

Long story - short

I would like to know how to swith YiiFramework English messages with Spanish inside Yii framework code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The internal framework messages should work, your config looks okay. Your own messages (the ones that you have written code for) will only be translated if you have used the `Yii::t()` function and if you provide the translation files.
3rd Party Code might or might not be comming with support for other languages, or like you said have their own system. In that case there is not much you can do, other than modify this code by yourself.
However internal Yii messages (model error messages for e.g.) should be translated to spanish now.

[more on translations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n)

Comment: Yes they are using Yii::T with translation module of their own design.
My config is as it is posted beofre but still I got 
"Please fix the following input errors:" instead of Spanish version of text.

Comment: I found out that there in code is redeclaration of   'language' => 'en', in db.php and by changing it I invoke the wraith of Sithis. as there are none DB tables for my language.